# Spring boot UUID error when I try to save a user

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I run a simple spring boot application and I try to save a user's id as UUID instead of Long or String. When I save the user using Long or String the endpoint operates normally but when I try to change the type of the id to UUID I get a status 500 error. Do you know how to fix it?

**here is the code:**

**User.java**

```
package com.example.restapi.Model;

import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.UUID;

@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private UUID id;
    @Column
    private String firstName;
    @Column
    private String lastName;
    @Column
    private int age;
    @Column
    private String occupation;

    public UUID getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(UUID id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getOccupation() {
        return occupation;
    }

    public void setOccupation(String occupation) {
        this.occupation = occupation;
    }
}
```

**UserRepo.java**

```
package com.example.restapi.Repo;

import com.example.restapi.Model.User;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import java.util.UUID;

public interface UserRepo extends JpaRepository<User, UUID> {


}
```

**ApiController.java**

```
package com.example.restapi.Controller;


import com.example.restapi.Model.User;
import com.example.restapi.Repo.UserRepo;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

@RestController
public class ApiController {
    @Autowired
    UserRepo userRepo;

    @GetMapping("/users")
    public List<User> getUsers(){
        return userRepo.findAll();
    }

    @PostMapping("/save")
    public String saveUser(@RequestBody User user){
        userRepo.save(user);
        return "Saved...";
    }

    @PutMapping("/update/{id}")
    public String updateUser(@PathVariable UUID id, @RequestBody User user){
        User updatedUser = userRepo.findById(id).get();
        updatedUser.setFirstName(user.getFirstName());
        updatedUser.setLastName(user.getLastName());
        updatedUser.setOccupation(user.getOccupation());
        updatedUser.setAge(user.getAge());
        userRepo.save(updatedUser);
        return "Updated";
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/delete/{id}")
    public String deleteUser(@PathVariable UUID id){
        User deleteUser = userRepo.findById(id).get();
        userRepo.delete(deleteUser);
        return "Delete user with id: "+id;
    }
}
```

**Here is the error I get from Postman:**

```
{
    "timestamp": "2022-10-04T08:58:23.331+00:00",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "path": "/save"
}
```

**Here is the error I get using Intelij IDEA:**

```
2022-10-04 11:58:23.325 ERROR 2752 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: unrecognized id type : uuid-binary -> java.util.UUID; nested exception is org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: unrecognized id type : uuid-binary -> java.util.UUID] with root cause

org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: unrecognized id type : uuid-binary -> java.util.UUID
    at org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGeneratorHelper.get(IdentifierGeneratorHelper.java:139) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGeneratorHelper.getGeneratedIdentity(IdentifierGeneratorHelper.java:77) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.dialect.identity.GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.java:62) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:43) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3279) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3885) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:84) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:645) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:282) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:317) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:330) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:287) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:193) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:123) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:185) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:128) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:55) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:756) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:742) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:362) ~[spring-orm-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy92.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:311) ~[spring-orm-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy92.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:666) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:289) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:530) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:286) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:640) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:164) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:81) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:174) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy95.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.example.restapi.Controller.ApiController.saveUser(ApiController.java:24) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1071) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:964) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1789) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

Comment: Why aren't you using String for id? You can still expect UUID from controller but when you are saving to/getting from DB, you can use UUID.toString() method.

Comment: An identity column is always a number not a UUID. So `GenerationType.IDENTITY` doesn't work with a UUID.

Answer (score 0):

As @M.Deinum has already alluded to `GenerationType.IDENTITY` will always provide a number.
[Blog post for more information](https://thorben-janssen.com/jpa-generate-primary-keys/#GenerationTypeIDENTITY)

You have two (in my opinion) good different options to use a UUID:

```
@Id
@UuidGenerator
//@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID) if you don't have @UuidGenerator. 
//They behave the same
private UUID id;
```

or

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = “UUID”)
@GenericGenerator(
  name = “UUID”,
  strategy = “org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator”,
  parameters = {
    @Parameter(
      name = “uuid_gen_strategy_class”,
      value = “org.hibernate.id.uuid.CustomVersionOneStrategy”
    )
  }
)
@Column(name = “id”, updatable = false, nullable = false)
private UUID id;
```

The second one will use more parameters to create the UUID. If that necessarily means less collision chances I don't know. But I doubt it.

More information in [this blog post](https://thorben-janssen.com/generate-uuids-primary-keys-hibernate/) by Thorben Janssen.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use **UUID** as primary key, you need to explicitly specify it to be **uuid-char**, or else it will be **uuid-binary** by default - which not allowed as primary key.

Just add another annotation like below :

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Type(type = "uuid-char")
private UUID id;
```

Comment: _it will be uuid-binary by default - which not allowed as primary key._ Source for that statement? I don't think this is true

Comment: I tried this but the error remains.